Posthog not sending events to new NextJS 14 installation, CORS issue
I followed the default installation steps but unable to receive the events in the dash board. I tried both eu and us api end points. The network tab was showing CORS errors.
Fresh installation and tried pointing to both EU and US.

I had the CORS issue on new NextJs deployment, and none of all the fixes and default installation docs worked. I had to do the rewrite in this link and point my logs to /ingest to resolve it. Hope this helps
https://posthog.com/docs/advanced/proxy/nextjs

I had the CORS issue on new NextJs deployment, and none of all the fixes and default installation docs worked. I had to do the rewrite in this link and point my logs to /ingest to resolve it. Hope this helps
https://posthog.com/docs/advanced/proxy/nextjs
